# unpacking dictionary in python and getting values

Tags: python, dictionary, iterable-unpacking

I have this dictionary and I am trying to extract the values

```
dict = {'distances': array([ 870.99793539]), 'labels': array([2])}
```

I tried to use

```
self.printit(**dict)

def printit(distances,labels):         
    print distances
    print labels
```

but I am getting error

```
TypeError: printit() got multiple values for keyword argument 'distances'
```

Comment: What is `prediction`?  Did you try just `print dict.values()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why you were getting a TypeError**:

When you call a method with `self.printit(**somedict)`, the first argument passed to the function `printit` is `self`. So if you define

```
def printit(distances, labels):
```

the `distances` is set to `self`. Since `somedict` contains a key called `distances`, the `distances` keyword is being supplied twice. 
That's the why the `TypeError` was being raised.

---

**How to fix it:**

Your function

```
def printit(distances,lables):
```

uses a variable named `lables`,  but the dict has a key spelled `labels`. You probably want to change `lables` to `labels`.

---

Add `self` as the first argument to `printit`.

```
def printit(self, distances, labels):
```

Calling the first argument `self` is just a convention -- you could call it something else (though that is not recommended) -- but you definitely *do* need to put some variable name there since calling

`self.printit(...)` will call `printit(self, ...)`.

---

**For example,**

```
import numpy as np
class Foo(object):
    def printit(self, distances, labels): 
            print distances
            print labels

somedict = {'distances': np.array([ 870.99793539]), 'labels': np.array([2])}
self = Foo()
self.printit(**somedict)
```

prints

```
[ 870.99793539]
[2]
```

---

Comment: thanq very much for ur answers. helped a lot

Answer (score 1):

You had a typo: `lables` instead of `labels`. This works fine:

```
from numpy import array

my_dict = {'distances': array([ 870.99793539]), 'labels': array([2])}

def printit(distances,labels): # changed lables to labels      
    print distances
    print labels # changed lables to labels

printit(**my_dict)
```

Result:

```
[ 870.99793539]
[2]
>>>
```